springboot startup error: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured
2024-10-05 15:56:41.577 |main |INFO  |org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener:136 |

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-10-05 15:56:41.725 |main |ERROR |org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:40 |

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles dev are currently active).

This is a springboot application, including druid datasource, nacos, mybatis. When I start the application, a startup error is reported. The above is the detailed startup error log.
Looking at the error message, I guessed that the data source was not configured properly, but I repeatedly checked the configuration items in nacos and found that the data source information was clearly configured, so I didn’t quite understand why this happened.
this is startup main class
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xx"})
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX,pattern = "com.xx.generator.*")})
@Slf4j
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class PublishApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PublishApplication.class,args);
    }
}

this is startup config
spring.cloud.nacos.config.file-extension=properties
spring.config.import=optional:nacos:mini-publish-server,optional:nacos:es,optional:nacos:redis,optional:nacos:public,optional:nacos:sa-token
spring.cloud.nacos.config.server-addr=172.16.102.25:8847,172.16.102.26:8847,172.16.102.27:8847
spring.cloud.nacos.config.username=nacos
spring.cloud.nacos.config.password=77tLQHAccDZZjWF
spring.cloud.nacos.config.namespace=ynhhz-mini-media-platform

spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.file-extension=properties
spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.username=nacos
spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.password=77tLQHAccDZZjWF
spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.server-addr=172.16.102.25:8847,172.16.102.26:8847,172.16.102.27:8847
spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.namespace=ynhhz-mini-media-platform

this is nacos config
spring.datasource.druid.web-stat-filter.enabled=false
spring.datasource.druid.stat-view-servlet.enabled=false
spring.datasource.druid.stat-view-servlet.allow=
spring.datasource.druid.stat-view-servlet.url-pattern=/druid/*
spring.datasource.druid.stat-view-servlet.login-username=druid
spring.datasource.druid.stat-view-servlet.login-password=1aG%3dP#94v
spring.datasource.druid.filter.stat.enabled=true
spring.datasource.druid.filter.stat.log-slow-sql=true
spring.datasource.druid.filter.stat.slow-sql-millis=100
spring.datasource.druid.filter.stat.merge-sql=true
spring.datasource.druid.filter.wall.config.multi-statement-allow=true
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.max-active=20
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.max-wait=600000
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=60000
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=300000
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.max-evictable-idle-time-millis=900000
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.validation-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.test-on-borrow=false
spring.datasource.dynamic.druid.test-on-return=false
spring.datasource.dynamic.primary=master
spring.datasource.dynamic.datasource.master.username=sprint01
spring.datasource.dynamic.datasource.master.password=Sprint02@mysql
spring.datasource.dynamic.datasource.master.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.dynamic.datasource.master.url=jdbc:mysql://172.16.102.25:3306/ynhhz_mini_media_platform?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai

